# Hide row with xlsx R package

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I would like to hide a row in a dataframe that I am writing to Excel using the xlsx package, but can't find a way to do this.

xlsx has the option of

```
SheetName$setColumnHidden(index, TRUE)
```

is there no equivalent to hide a single row?

I tried `SheetName$setRowGroupCollapsed(rownumber, TRUE)`, but this hid all rows in the dataframe when saving to Excel

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
library(tidyverse)

col1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
col2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

data <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

```
> data

  col1 col2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    3    c
4    4    d
5    5    e
```

notice how there are row names to the left of col1?

you can do:

```
> data %>% 
    filter(row.names(.) != 1)

  col1 col2
1    2    b
2    3    c
3    4    d
4    5    e
```

or:

```
> data %>% 
    filter(col1 != 1)

  col1 col2
1    2    b
2    3    c
3    4    d
4    5    e
```

then you do:

```
> data <- data %>% 
    filter(col1 != 1)

> data

  col1 col2
1    2    b
2    3    c
3    4    d
4    5    e
```

then `write.xlsx(data, "abc.xlsx", sheetname = "poop")`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is removing the row from the dataframe - I'm hoping there's a way to write to Excel with the row hidden but still present, similar to setColumnHidden in the xlsx package. I need the row still present, but hidden for display purposes.